# Installation steps for Xrdp on Ubuntu 18 enabling connection from Mac OS X Sierra to Ubuntu 18

Tags: networking, macbook-pro, xrdp

What are the specific installation steps for Xrdp on Ubuntu 18 enabling connection from Mac OS X Sierra to Ubuntu 18?

I have tried installing and hit problems - all help gratefully received.

### Problem

I installed Ubuntu 18 directly on a MacBook Pro 2015 all is fine except for remote access via XRDP. I have multiple machines hence Microsoft Remote desktop access is preferred. I installed Xrdp using the instructions [here](https://help.skysilk.com/support/discussions/topics/9000042405) but encounter problems on the connection:

1. A black screen with a displayed error: "Could not acquire name on session bus" on the first connection

[image]

2. A black screen for a 10 to 20 seconds
3. Then a desktop with two errors prompts

[image]

**Situation**

- MacBook Pro 2018 Mac OS X Sierra
- MacBook Pro 2015 Ubuntu 18

I did a clean install on the MacBook Pro 2015 of Ubuntu 18.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have simply used outdated information as you have followed instructions for installing xrdp on top of Ubuntu 16.04 (which are originally coming from this [blog](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=8952)).  My suggestion would be to use the new instructions available for Ubuntu 18.04 as a lot of changes have been introduced in this version....

New xrdp package is available in Ubuntu 18.04 and you can get the detailed info to perform a scripted install on your Ubuntu 18.04.  You have multiple versions of the script... the latest one provide more features and options ([http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=12551]) [2](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=12551)

If you want to play it safe and try a simpler version of the script, you could try the version 0.3 (which can be founded at http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=12198

Hope this help
Till next time 
See ya